# How to include (script-built) libraries with package installation?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-c-api

I am making a Python package that has a C++-extension module and someone else's shared library that it requires. I want everything installable via `pip`. My current `setup.py` file works when I use `pip install -e .` but when I don't use develop mode (e.i. omit the `-e`) I get *"cannot open shared object file"* when importing the module in Python. I believe the reason is that setuptools doesn't consider the shared library to be part of my package, so the relative link to the library is broken during installation when files are copied to the install directory.

Here is what my `setup.py` file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, Command
import setuptools.command.develop
import setuptools.command.build_ext
import setuptools.command.install
import distutils.command.build
import subprocess
import sys
import os

# This function downloads and builds the shared-library
def run_clib_install_script():
    build_clib_cmd = ['bash', 'clib_install.sh']
    if subprocess.call(build_clib_cmd) != 0:
        sys.exit("Failed to build C++ dependencies")

# I make a new command that will build the shared-library
class build_clib(Command):
    user_options = []
    def initialize_options(self):
        pass
    def finalize_options(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        run_clib_install_script()

# I subclass install so that it will call my new command
class install(setuptools.command.install.install):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_clib')
        setuptools.command.install.install.run(self)

# I do the same for build...
class build(distutils.command.build.build):
    sub_commands = [
        ('build_clib', lambda self: True),
        ] + distutils.command.build.build.sub_commands

# ...and the same for develop
class develop(setuptools.command.develop.develop):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_clib')
        setuptools.command.develop.develop.run(self)

# These are my includes...
# note that /clib/include only exists after calling clib_install.sh
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
include_dirs = [
    cwd,
    cwd + '/clib/include',
    cwd + '/common',
]

# These are my arguments for the compiler to my shared-library
lib_path = os.path.join(cwd, "clib", "lib")
library_dirs = [lib_path]
link_args = [os.path.join(lib_path, "libclib.so")]

# My extension module gets these arguments so it can link to clib
mygen_module = Extension('mygen',
                    language="c++14",
                    sources=["common/mygen.cpp"],
                    libraries=['clib'],
                    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++14'],
                    include_dirs=include_dirs,
                    library_dirs=library_dirs,
                    extra_link_args=link_args
                        + ['-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../clib/lib'])

# I use cmdclass to override the default setuptool commands
setup(name='mypack',
      cmdclass = {'install': install,
                  'build_clib': build_clib, 'build': build,
                  'develop': develop},
      packages=['mypack'],
      ext_package='mypack',
      ext_modules=[mygen_module],
      # package_dir={'mypack': '.'},
      # package_data={'mypack': ['docs/*md']},
      include_package_data=True)
```

I subclass some of the setuptools commands in order to build the shared-library before it compiles the extension. `clib_install.sh` is a bash script that locally downloads and builds the shared library in `/clib`, creating the headers (in `/clib/include`) and .so file (in `/clib/lib`). To solve problems with linking to shared-library dependencies I used `$ORIGIN/../clib/lib` as a link argument so that the absolute path to `clib` isn't needed.

Unfortunately, the `/clib` directory doesn't get copied to the install location. I tried tinkering with `package_data` but it didn't copy my directory over. In fact, I don't even know what pip/setuptools does with `/clib` after the script is called, I guess it is made in some temporary build directory and gets deleted after. I am not sure how to get `/clib` to where it needs to be after it is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package_data={
    'mypack': [
        'clib/include/*.h',
        'clib/lib/*.so',
        'docs/*md',
    ]
},
```